# Is there any rule as to what happens if you roll a fumble that turns out to be less than 1?

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy, fumbles

I know the 'core exxet' removed any modifiers to degree of fumble, as was, but in the old rules where fumbles had a +15, 0, or -15 according to whether they were 1, 2, or 3, what was supposed to happen if you rolled <16 on a fumble at a 3?  There isn't a result on the table for it.

Answer (score 1):

In Anima, fumble can only occurs on a **natural** 01-03 (01-05 with disadvantage).

The rules about fumbles are quite easy (as described in Core Exxet - p.007-008):

> When the player rolls a **natural** 01-03 the action is automatically failure. You then  have to proceed to the level of failure by rolling a non-opened D100.

For an opposition roll (offense action vs defense action, search vs hide, etc) you substract the level of failure to your skill. In the case of initiative, you substract a specific value (Core Exxet - p096-097).

The +15 / 0 / -15 in the 1st Edition where added to mitigate the level of failure. (so added to the level of failure roll). 
For example:

- Bob has a Bastard Sword skill of 100
- Bob roll a 01 on his attack. This is a fumble with a +15 modifier.
- Bob roll a 90 level of failure.
- With 1st ed rules, his attack roll would be: 100 - (90 + 15) = 100 - 105 = -5

So Bob final attack roll is -5.

Now your case:

- Alice has a Bastard Sword skill of 100
- Alice roll a 03 on his attack. This is a fumble with a -15 modifier.
- Alice roll a 90 level of failure.
- With 1st ed rules, his attack roll would be: 100 - (90 - 15) = 100 - 75 = 25

So Alice final attack roll is 25.

New case (totally corresponding to question case):

- Alice has a Bastard Sword skill of 100
- Alice rolls a 03 on his attack. This is a fiumble with a -15 modifier
- Alice rolls a 5 for level of failure.
- With 1st ed rules, his attack roll would be: 100 - (5 - 15) = 100 - (-10) = 100 + 10 = 110

As for all non opposition rolls, the text is quite clear: "If the level of failure is below 50..." (1st Edition - p.046), then basic arithmetics (-10 < 50)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111812/discussion-on-answer-by-churam-is-there-any-rule-as-to-what-happens-if-you-roll).